# how to swipe between activity (where is my code wrong???)

Tags: android, android-viewpager, swipe

I have 4 activity that have 4 class & xml layout ; i want to swipe between in 4 activity !!
i use this code from another post (This Post: [Fling gesture detection on grid layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313/android-basic-gesture-detection))

i want when touching leftToright Or rightToleft swipe with opening new activity.

where is my code is wrong :

my code :

```
package com.package110.Y;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log; 
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class ActivitySwipeDetectorActivity extends Activity {
   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

 // how to set this 3 line to in my code Or change or update it        

 //ActivitySwipeDetector activitySwipeDetector = new ActivitySwipeDetector(this);
 //lowestLayout = (RelativeLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.lowestLayout);
 //lowestLayout.setOnTouchListener(activitySwipeDetector);

   }




    public class ActivitySwipeDetector implements View.OnTouchListener {


            Intent left = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), left.class);
            Intent right = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), right.class);
            Intent top = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), top.class);
            Intent bottom = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), bottom.class);


        static final String logTag = "ActivitySwipeDetector";
        private Activity activity;
        static final int MIN_DISTANCE = 100;
        private float downX, downY, upX, upY;

        public ActivitySwipeDetector(Activity activity){
            this.activity = activity;
        }

        public void onRightToLeftSwipe(){
            Log.i(logTag, "RightToLeftSwipe!");
            activity.startActivity(right);

        }

        public void onLeftToRightSwipe(){
            Log.i(logTag, "LeftToRightSwipe!");
            activity.startActivity(left);
        }

        public void onTopToBottomSwipe(){
            Log.i(logTag, "onTopToBottomSwipe!");
            activity.startActivity(top);
        }

        public void onBottomToTopSwipe(){
            Log.i(logTag, "onBottomToTopSwipe!");
            activity.startActivity(bottom);
        }

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch(event.getAction()){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                    downX = event.getX();
                    downY = event.getY();
                    return true;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                    upX = event.getX();
                    upY = event.getY();

                    float deltaX = downX - upX;
                    float deltaY = downY - upY;

                    // swipe horizontal?
                    if(Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE){
                        // left or right
                        if(deltaX < 0) { this.onLeftToRightSwipe(); return true; }
                        if(deltaX > 0) { this.onRightToLeftSwipe(); return true; }
                    }
                    else {
                            Log.i(logTag, "Swipe was only " + Math.abs(deltaX) + " long, need at least " + MIN_DISTANCE);
                            return false; // We don't consume the event
                    }

                    // swipe vertical?
                    if(Math.abs(deltaY) > MIN_DISTANCE){
                        // top or down
                        if(deltaY < 0) { this.onTopToBottomSwipe(); return true; }
                        if(deltaY > 0) { this.onBottomToTopSwipe(); return true; }
                    }
                    else {
                            Log.i(logTag, "Swipe was only " + Math.abs(deltaX) + " long, need at least " + MIN_DISTANCE);
                            return false; // We don't consume the event
                    }

                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        }



  }
```

explain:
my app is force close !!!
my google API is for android 3.0 ; does it have make problem for my app ?
and also i try this code and it force close !!!!

another code :

```
package ir.package110.Y;


 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.GestureDetector;
 import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
 import android.view.MotionEvent;
 import android.view.View;

 public class ActivitySwipeDetectorActivity extends Activity {
          private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

          @Override
          public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.main);


              // ...

            gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new SwipeGestureDetector());
          }

          /* ... */

            Intent right = new Intent(ActivitySwipeDetectorActivity.this.getBaseContext(), right.class);
            Intent left = new Intent(ActivitySwipeDetectorActivity.this.getBaseContext(), left.class);



          private void onLeftSwipe() {
            // Do something
            startActivity(left);

          }

          private void onRightSwipe() {
            startActivity(right);

              // Do something
          }

          // Private class for gestures
          private class SwipeGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
            // Swipe properties, you can change it to make the swipe
            // longer or shorter and speed
            private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
            private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 200;
            private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;

            @Override
            public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                                 float velocityX, float velocityY) {
              try {
                float diffAbs = Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY());
                float diff = e1.getX() - e2.getX();

                if (diffAbs > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                  return false;

                // Left swipe
                if (diff > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    ActivitySwipeDetectorActivity.this.onLeftSwipe();

                // Right swipe
                } else if (-diff > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    ActivitySwipeDetectorActivity.this.onRightSwipe();
                }
              } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("YourActivity", "Error on gestures");
              }
              return false;
            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: Try using a `fragment`s! That's what I did when I need something like this and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to do that is one single Activity and 4 fragments, with a ViewPager.

You can check this link about fragments:
http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam;jsessionid=A2DD7A11C804B7C7646DCA883AA452FC?recipeId=1160

And this one about ViewPager:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

Answer (score 0):

You **should** use `Fragment`s. It makes navigation much cleaner.

`Fragment`s run inside of an `Activity`, and can look and function just like an `Activity`!

Here is some code.

**`Activity` to hold `Fragment`s**

*(Tabs and `ActionBar` can be hidden)*

```
public class Activity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(R.style.ScoreBoardStyles);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view_pager);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
        // the ViewPager.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
        // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
        // a reference to the Tab.
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                    .setCustomView(t)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }
    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            if (position == 0) {
                fragment = new FirstFragment();
            }
            if (position == 1) {
                fragment = new SecondFragment();
            }
            if (position == 2) {
                fragment = new ThirdFragment();
            }
            if (position == 3) {
                fragment = new FourthFragment();
            }
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 4;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
                case 1:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
                case 2:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
                case 3:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section4).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

**Example of a `Fragment`**

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

    public ScoreFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_layout, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        // YOUR CODE HERE
    }
}
```

**If you are using `AndroidStudio`!**

1. Right click your com.blah.bleh
2. Go to New
3. Select create new `TabbedActivity` (Choose your navigation style towards bottom)

Then create your `Fragment`s

1. Right click your com.blah.bleh
2. Go to New
3. Select `Fragment` and choose your `Fragment` type

Set the layout in your `Activity` class here

```
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        if (position == 0) {
            fragment = new FirstFragment();
        }
        if (position == 1) {
            fragment = new SecondFragment();
        }
        if (position == 2) {
            fragment = new ThirdFragment();
        }
        if (position == 3) {
            fragment = new FourthFragment();
        }
        return fragment;
    }
```

Hope that helps!